# Why do options with long strings have a double dash?

Tags: command-line, flag

Why do Command Line flags like `--recursive` have two dashes instead of just `-recursive`?

I know that the shortened version is just `-r`.

Why do these flags use two hyphens rather than one hyphen?

Is there a maximum number of characters that a flag with one dash can have before it requires two dashes?

Comment: this may be helpful: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html  also this: http://leo.ugr.es/elvira/devel/Tutorial/Java/essential/attributes/_posix.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that you can say things like `ls -laR`;
it’s equivalent to `ls -l -a -R`. 
So `-recursive` would be interpreted as `-r -e -c -u -r -s -i -v -e`.

Comment: its also used to allow long arguments and to let you pass arguments to an option without confusion.

Answer (score 1):

There's no exact rule to use single or double dash as an option to a program. If one decided to handle options on one's own one can implement whatever one want.
But if programmer isn't looking for a PITA and want the program to use common, well recognizable way then one would use standard function(s) `getopt/getopt_long` that handle long options (long string as you asked) as double dashed an short options(single character) prefixed with single dash. The function `getopt` is part of `<unistd.h>` in C language. The same function can be used on Unix based systems in standard shells `man getopt 1` that utilize parsing single and double dashed (long) options.

> Is there a maximum number of characters that a flag with one dash can have before it requires two dashes?

If one uses function described above then short options can have only one single character.